# Adjektivdeklination: -e oder -en?

Tags: adjective-ending, declension

I‘m learning Adjektivdeklination from a workbook, and I came to this question where I believe the answer of the book is false.

> Heute ist einer der heißest_ Tage des ganzen Jahres.

The answer written in the book is:

> heißest**e**

, whereas

> Tage

is plural and, thus, it should be, I think:

> heißest**en**

Can anyone please assist me in that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch. Your object *Tage* is in plural (plural genitive more precisely). Therefore, the ending of the corresponding adjective must be *-en*

Comment: Oh, thanks for the validation. Anyone studying from [telc Grammatiktraining Deutsch für B2](https://www.telc.net/shop/detail/article/grammatiktraining-deutsch-fuer-b2.html?p=243) like me, pay attention to this mistake on page 47 Exercise 1 part b number 10 :) It just adds more stress to the learner ;)

Answer (score 2):

Singular:

> Heute ist der heißeste Tag des ganzen Jahres.
> Today is the hottest day of the whole year.

Plural:

> Heute ist einer der heißesten Tage des ganzen Jahres.
> Today is one of the hottest days of the whole year.

Comment: Füge am Ende einer Zeile 2 Leerzeichen ein, dann gelingt auch der Zeilenumbruch. Ich habe deine Antwort entsprechend editiert.